# Wikipedia Integration. How?

Tags: wikipedia-api

If I wanted to import few lines of a document from Wikipedia into my site. How can I do this?

For example if I had a page about Google and I wanted to just import first paragraph about Google directly from Wikipedia is there an API that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki does have an API for all of the MediaWiki databases (Including Wikipedia), which can be found on the [API page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) of the MediaWiki website. There is [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to go along with it, although it seems a bit verbose.

Comment: Which is the same as my initial link :)

Comment: sorry, I guess I assumed that was a link to the MediaWiki main page.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, ah yes, probably due to my wording. Thanks for fixing it :)

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia uses the MediaWiki API:  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API